# How to obtain last three lines content of a log file using VBScript function

Tags: html, vb.net, vbscript, hta

Can anyone suggest me a **VBscript function to get the last 3 lines** of a text document (for eg: **log.txt** ? Below is my code which  can fetch and display the entire log on my screen but I want to get **only last 3 lines of the log file** named log.txt.

```
<script type="text/Vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim File
File = "C:\\test.txt"
'***********************************************************
Sub LoadMyFile()
    myDiv.innerHTML = LoadFile(File)
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LoadFile(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso,F,ReadMe,Tab,i,paragraphe
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    LoadFile = Err.Number
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        MsgBox Err.Description,16," Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    Tab = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    For i = lbound(Tab) to ubound(Tab)
        paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
    Next
    LoadFile = paragraphe
End Function
</script>
```

**Code not working@Steve**

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/Vbscript">
    Option Explicit
    Dim File
    File = "C:\\test.txt"
    '***********************************************************
    Sub LoadMyFile()
        myDiv.innerHTML = LoadFile(File)
    End Sub
    ************************************************************
    Function CheckProcesses()
    dim startLine
On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso,F,ReadMe,Tab,i,paragraphe
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    LoadFile = Err.Number
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        MsgBox Err.Description,16," Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    Tab = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    For i = lbound(Tab) to ubound(Tab)
        paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
    Next
    if ubound(Tab) > 2 Then
       startLine = ubound(Tab) - 2
    else
       startLine = 0
    end if
    For i = startLine to ubound(Tab)
        paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
    Next
    LoadFile = paragraphe
    End Function
    </script>
     <input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="Log Dctm" onclick="CheckProcesses()"></html>
```

Thanks and regards
Deb

Comment: I can't help you if you post your comment on a different answer. However, if you look at the code added above you will notice that you havent' removed the previous loop that builds the `paragraphe` string. This means that your `paragraphe` string consists of all the previous lines plus the last three lines. You should remove the code that loops over the full tab array and leave only my changes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an array of lines (Tab), the last n lines to display start from UBound(Tab) - n + 1 and end with UBound(Tab). You should test for 'less than n lines in Tab' and for 'is last line of Tab  empty (trailing EOL)'.

Comment: @Steve  I tried to make the changes in my code but it is not working. I have pasted my changed code(changed code) in my original thread as above, is there something I am doing incorrect kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that avoids memory exhaustion with large files:

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.txt"
numlines = 3

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'create and initialize ring buffer
ReDim buf(numlines-1)
For n = 0 To UBound(buf)
  buf(n) = Null
Next
i = 0

'read lines into ring buffer
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  buf(i) = f.ReadLine
  i = (i+1) Mod numlines
Loop
f.Close

'output ringbuffer content (skip null values)
For n = 1 To numlines
  If Not IsNull(buf(i)) Then WScript.Echo buf(i)
  i = (i+1) Mod numlines
Next
```

The array `buf` in combination with the index variable `i` and the modulo operation serves as a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer) containing the last lines read from the file (`numlines` at most).

At the end of the second loop (the one reading the input file), the index `i` points towards the array field *after* the one containing the last line read from the file, i.e. the beginning of the buffer.

The `Null` values from the array initialization let the output routine "slide" to the first content line (or the end of the buffer) if less than `numlines` lines were read from the file. The variable `n` in the output loop is just a counter so that the `numlines` elements from the ring buffer are read starting at index `i` and ending at index `i-1` (modulo wrapping).

Comment: Shouldn't `For n = 1 To numlines` be `For n = i To numlines` (i not 1)?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner No. `i` could be any position in the ring buffer, depending on the number of lines in the input file, so I need to output the buffer from `i` to `i-1` (modulo wrapping). `n` is just a counter to ensure that exactly `numlines` fields from the buffer are processed. I could have used a loop like `n = i : Do ... Loop Until i = n` instead, but I thought the `For` loop would be easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I see it now (*after* your explanation).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I added some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Ekkehard, thanks for your suggestions. But someone has added 2 negative ratings on my question which blocked me from future use of stack overflow. Do you see my question as invalid one? I dont see a single cause behind it. Anyways thanks again for all your help

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Thanks a ton for all constructive suggestions..but someone provided negative marks to my question which blocked me from future use.Not sure what looks invalid about my question, I find it ok.

Comment: @Dojo_user Be sure to read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) (and its answers) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to test this, but If you know the `UBound` of the variable `Tab`, then the last three lines are `UBound(tab)-2`, `UBound(tab)-1` and `UBound(tab)`.

```
For i = ubound(Tab) - 2 to ubound(Tab)
    paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
Next
```

Of course this requires that you have at least 3 lines in your log file, so, perhaps a little check should be done before entering the loop

```
dim startLine
if ubound(Tab) > 2 Then
   startLine = ubound(Tab) - 2
else
   startLine = 0
end if
For i = startLine to ubound(Tab)
    paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
Next
```

Comment: Please change `UBound(tab-x)` to `UBound(tab)-x`.

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution**

You can use this function :

`Function ExtractLinesFromTextFile(ByRef TextFile, ByRef FromLine, ByRef ToLine)`

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,FromLine,ToLine,fso,Readfile,strBuff,InputFile,TotalNbLines
Title = "Extract Lines From TextFile © Hackoo 2014"
InputFile = "c:\test.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Readfile = Fso.OpenTextFile(InputFile,1)
strBuff = Readfile.ReadAll
TotalNbLines = Readfile.Line
Readfile.Close
MsgBox "The total number of lines in this file """& InputFile &""" = "& TotalNbLines,VbInformation,Title
'To extract the 3 last lines
MsgBox ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,TotalNbLines - 2,TotalNbLines),64,Title
'*********************************************************************************************************
Public Function ExtractLinesFromTextFile(ByRef TextFile, ByRef FromLine, ByRef ToLine) '<-- Inclusive
    Const TristateUseDefault = -2 'To Open the file using the system default.
    On Error Resume Next
    If FromLine <= ToLine Then
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(TextFile,1,true,TristateUseDefault)
            If Err.number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox err.description,16,err.description
                Exit Function
            Else
                Do Until .Line = FromLine Or .AtEndOfStream
                    .SkipLine
                Loop
                Do Until .Line > ToLine Or .AtEndOfStream
                    ExtractLinesFromTextFile = ExtractLinesFromTextFile & (.ReadLine & vbNewLine)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Error to Read Line in TextFile", vbCritical,"Error to Read Line in TextFile"
    End If
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************************
```