# VBscript for copying and pasting data from .txt to .xlsx

Tags: excel, vbscript

Looking to create a script for copying the last 8 or so lines from a txt file into cell A, 3 of an Excel file.  This is what I have put together so far and it does not work.   Basically copying from tab delimited to an excel template file.  Please help as I have only written very basic scripts in VB so far.

Here is what I'm working with so far....

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", ForReading)
for i = Last 8 lines
objTextFile.ReadLine
Next
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Wscript.Echo strLine
objTextFile.Close



Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\NBP ESP-152 REV F TEMPLATE.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add = i
objExcel.Cells(a, 3).Value = strLine
```

The below script from Aedvald works up until the point of where it is supposed to paste into the workbook:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' get number of lines
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test.txt", ForReading)
objTextFile.ReadAll
lineCount = objTextFile.Line
objTextFile.Close


Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test.txt", ForReading)

' skip all lines except 8 last
i = 0
while i < lineCount-8
 objTextFile2.ReadLine
 i = i+1
wend

' prepare excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\NBP ESP-152 REV F 
TEMPLATE.xlsx")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True

j = 1
' read last 8 lines
Do Until objTextFile2.AtEndOfStream
  ' read line
  line = objTextFile2.ReadLine
  ' write to console
  ' WScript.Echo line (for testing)
  ' and into workbook
  objExcel.Cells(1, j).Value = strLine
  j=j+1
Loop
```

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/24035730/603855 helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain last three lines content of a log file using VBScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035730/how-to-obtain-last-three-lines-content-of-a-log-file-using-vbscript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to make it work:

I Open test.txt and loop over all lines in order to count them. Then I open test.txt again and loop till there are only 8 lines left. Then I loop over the 8 remaining lines while adding them to the cells of the first worksheet of the Excel-Workbook.

**Update:** To add text to Excel-Sheet, the cells-property of worksheet has to be used:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel

====

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' get number of lines
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", ForReading)
objTextFile.ReadAll
lineCount = objTextFile.Line
objTextFile.Close


Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", ForReading)

' skip all lines except 8 last
i = 0
while i < lineCount-8
  objTextFile2.ReadLine
  i = i+1
wend

' prepare excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\NBP ESP-152 REV F TEMPLATE.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

j = 1
' read last 8 lines
Do Until objTextFile2.AtEndOfStream
  ' read line
  line = objTextFile2.ReadLine
  ' write to console
  ' WScript.Echo line ' (for testing)
  ' and into workbook
  objWorksheet.Cells(1, j).Value =  line
  j=j+1
Loop
```

Comment: This is great, for some reason when I execute though the lines show up in message boxes instead of being pasted into excel template.  thanks for your help!

Comment: After testing the corrections above, it still fails to paste into the workbook for some reason.

Comment: I just fixed it.To add text to Excel-Sheet, the cells-property of worksheet has to be used. Plese accept my corrected answer.